# Создался в Eclipse public class Snippet.

Tags: java, eclipse

В Eclipse неожиданно появился

```
package snippet;

public class Snippet {
//и текст из клипбоард 
}
```

Я такое название не давал классу и слов таких не знаю. Это какой то вирус, или я просто не туда нажал. Вопрос не праздный. Может у меня удаленно кто то хозяйничает.

Comment: Это готовые кусочки кода, которые можно использовать. Вы случайно нажали на кнопку, которая их вставляет.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо

Comment: Писать в ответ?
http://www.simplecoding.org/effektivnoe-ispolzovanie-eclipse.html

Comment: Конечно пишите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сниппеты - готовые кусочки кода, облегчают жизнь.
http://www.simplecoding.org/effektivnoe-ispolzovanie-eclipse.html